# iOS: NSNumberFormatter doesn't convert string back to NSNumber

Tags: ios, textfield, nsnumberformatter

I am using following NSNumberFormatter to add commas and symbol in the currency value.

```
self.currencyFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
self.currencyFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
self.currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = @"£";
self.currencyFormatter.currencyCode = @"GBP";
self.currencyFormatter.roundingMode = NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp;
self.currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0;
```

Usage:

```
self.principleAmountTextField.text = [self.currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:100000]];
```

This displays £100,000 as expected. Now if I insert two more digits (text becomes £100,00096) in textfield and try to convert string to Integer I get 0! Basically following line returns 0. I have no idea how to deal with this issue.

```
NSLog(@"%d", [[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"£100,00096"] integerValue]);
```

FYI I have custom inputview to textfield which just allows numbers to enter into textfield. In Did Edit End even I format number and display with comma.

Comment: `£100,00096` isn't a valid number. `£10,000,096` would be as well as `£10000096`.

Comment: ....but I can't put commas when user enter's the number! Is there anyway numbers automatically converted to required format as being entered?

Comment: If the user can enter invalid value you will need to strip any grouping characters from the string before trying to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the commas for this to work, you can still show them in your text field but you should strip them out before you pass the string to the formatter. Something like this:

```
NSString *userInput = @"£100,00096";    
userInput = [userInput stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
NSLog(@"%ld", (long)[[currencyFormatter numberFromString:userInput] integerValue]);
```

Comment: Do not hard code commas into the code. Based on the user's locale, different characters could be used. It would be better to get the grouping character from the number formatter.

Answer (score 0):

`100,00096` isn't correct...

Do you mean one of these?

```
[[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"£10000096"] integerValue]
[[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"£100,000.96"] integerValue]
[[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"£100000.96"] integerValue]
[[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:@"£10,000,096"] integerValue]
```

Comment: ...no when user enter's number they just append. For instance you already have £100,000 in the textfield. Now they start entering number and it will be appended as £100,000 + whatever entered. They can just enter numbers not commas. In didEditEnd I am formatting number.

Comment: Sure, but then you need to re-format what you're showing the user while they're entering numbers. `100,00096` isn't a correct way to display any number.

Answer (score 0):

My final code for the reference. The number with currency symbol also an invalid! Following takes care of everything.

```
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.currencyFormatter.groupingSeparator, self.currencyFormatter.currencySymbol]];
    self.amountTextField.text = [[self.amountTextField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    self.amountTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"£%@", self.amountTextField.text];
    NSUInteger amount = [[self.currencyFormatter numberFromString:self.amountTextField.text] integerValue];
    self.amountTextField.text = [self.currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:amount]]
```